# Where do people get earnings information directly when it's released?

Tags: research, news, quarterly-report

Whenever a company releases its quarterly earnings, I'm sitting on google refreshing waiting for a new article to show up with the details. By the time that happens, generally the stock already reflects Wall Street's opinion of the quarterly report's contents.

If a stock is set to "release quarterly results after the bell," where can you go to get those results directly and immediately, as fast as any other entity gets them?

Comment: While not a full answer, the Robinhood app can send you notifications when a company is going to do an earnings call.  You can even listen in on the call in many cases.

Answer (score 2):

To get the news 'directly and immediately', you need real time streaming news.  The premier service is an expensive  Bloomberg terminal.

Many years ago, I used to trade earnings announcements.  I subscribed to Dow Jones Streaming News ($39.95 a month).  I think that the first broker I used for this was Datek Securities (Ameritrade bought them 15+ years ago).  Their subscription offered the ability to input 5 lists of 20 symbols, each list having a different color code.  If news was released from one of these, the colorized symbol stood out as the news story scrolled down the page (all other stories were in white print).   I stayed with Ameritrade for awhile until some years later I found out that if you parked $500 in a Scottrade account, DJ News was free.

I don't know what's out there now  (other services and price) but with some Googling, you might find something more attractive than full price :->)

A free  alternative is if your broker offers price alerts, bracket the closing price in both directions.  You won't know what the news is but you'll certainly see the direction.  And given that you don't have the time to read EA details, price may be all that you need.

Answer (score 1):

Many companies have an investor website where filings will be published and the timing of the announcement will appear there prior to publishing.  Here are the investor relations pages for [Apple](https://investor.apple.com/investor-relations/default.aspx) and [Teleflex](https://www.teleflex.com/usa/en/investor/index) as examples.  Additionally, the [SEC EDGAR](https://www.sec.gov/edgar/searchedgar/companysearch.html) system can be searched.

Comment: Events like conference calls are scheduled (your Apple link).  Earnings announcements are listed only as Before Market Open, During, and After Market. Many do it exactly at 4 PM.  Many are delayed for minutes to a good part of an hour, for whatever the reason..

Comment: @BobBaerker that's a fair distinction.

Answer (score 0):

Typically companies (as they do with all other press releases) send them to a newswire service.  If you get the actual notice that was sent out, it typically states which news wire it went out on.  If not, you could ask their investor relations group who may be able to tell you, and whether or not they publish it at the same time on their own website.

Some of the news wires have twitter accounts, and you may be able to contact them directly for a subscription (though this tends to be the same service they offer the media companies, so may be quite expensive).  They may in turn be able to point you to subscribers who offer the service to individuals (including Bloomberg).  You can shop around for the ones that offer it in the most timely manner and for the lowest prices.

However, many news services have figured out that some people have algorithms that scan for key words that send in orders to trade automatically, so offer 'API' services at a *quite* considerable premium.  Your broker may bundle news services with your brokerage account or for an additional fee.